# match part of a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to identify list (`li`) items that include a full stop at the very end.

I can work out how to match a full string with

```
if ($(obj).elements[0].innerHTML === "This list has full stops."
```

but don't know how to match just a full stop at the end.  I tried

```
if ($(obj).elements[0].innerHTML === "*."
```

but no good.

Please help

Comment: Use regex like `if(/\.$/.test($(obj).elements[0].innerHTML))`

Comment: You require the text to end with a `.` character, right and nothing else after that?

Comment: Thanks everybody for your help, it really is appreciated.  I was able to copy exactly from Arun P Johny and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (/.*?\.$/.test($(obj).elements[0].innerHTML) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a big fan of regex, however if you want to do the above thing multiple times and make code easily readable you can create a function for it.

```
function endsWith(str, suffix) {
    return str.indexOf(suffix, str.length - suffix.length) !== -1;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
var str = $(obj).elements[0].innerHTML;
if(endsWith(str,'.')){
  // Do watever.
}
```